# DataTables rowGroup not grouping every item correctly

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a table with 4 columns grouped by the second one, when rendering the page, not every group contains every row with that name, I checked that they share the same grouping name because when uncollapsing the group every group of the same name performs this action.

[screenshot of some groups collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2tkA.png)

[screenshot of some groups uncollapsed by clicking just the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yah8j.png)

The issue is that I haven't being able to group every row that shares the same name and apparently they have the exact same string as data (trimmed in code), also, when sorting by date for some reason it changes the result of the sum of the third column, and I'm not sure why (sorting high to low give the correct answer but .

the code is as follows:

HTML table creation

```
<table id="table_1" class="table table-bordered compact display" style="width:100%">
                    <thead class="text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th>AcctCode</th>
                            <th>Nombre cuenta</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach($valores as $dat){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo trim($dat['Cuenta_Contable']) ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo trim($dat['Nombre_cuenta'])?></td>
                            <td data-order="<?php echo $dat['Total'];?>"><?php echo $dat['Total']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php 
                                    
                                    $date = new DateTime($dat['Fecha']);
                                    $date_format = $date->format('Y-m-d')   ;
                                    echo $date_format;
                                
                                ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                    
                </table>
```

Javascript creating the table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            
        
            const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL',{
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'CLP'
            });

            var usr_type = <?php echo $_SESSION['grupo']; ?>;

            var collapsedGroups = {};

            var table = $('#table_1').DataTable({
                //columnDefs: [{visible:false, targets: 0}],
                paging: false,
                order: [[1, 'des']],
                "dom": '<lf<t>ip>',
                "lengthChange": true,
                rowGroup: {
                  dataSrc: 1,
                  startRender: function(rows, group) {
                      
                      
                      var suma = 0;
                      var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[group];
                      rows.nodes().each(function(r){
                          r.style.display = 'none';
                          if (collapsed){
                              r.style.display = '';
                          }
                          suma += rows.data()[0][2].display*1;

                      });
                      

                      
                      return $('<tr/>')
                        .append('<td colspan="2">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td><td colspan="2">' + formatter.format(suma) + ' </td></td>')
                        .attr('data-name', group)
                        .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);


                  }
                }
              });

              $('#table_1 tbody').on('click', 'tr.dtrg-group', function() {
                var name = $(this).data('name');
                collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
                table.draw(false);
              });
        })
```

I have tried sorting by the code on the first column, modifying the strings on the table's cells, reading references of rowGroups and reading the browser's interpretation of the code, but I haven't found the cause of this.

Thank you all in advance.